# Check worksheet name with win32com

Tags: python, python-2.6, win32com

I have a program that reads data from a worksheet in an already opened excel file. However if the wrong file/worksheet is open the data will be corrupted.

I initiate excel using the following. But I cannot find an object of xcel that contains filename or worksheet name.

```
import win32com.client
xcel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
```

What I am looking for is a way to read the filename of the excel file and the name of the worksheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no filename if you open a new excel application ... 
You open a new file this way `excel.Workbooks.Open(Filename,ReadOnly)`

And this is for checking sheet name

```
import win32com.client
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')

wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
ws = wb.Sheets(1)

if ws.Name!="TheSheetImLookingFor":
    raise ValueError(ws.Name)
```